# How to add MQA (Mobile Quality Assurance) to an existing MobileFirst hybrid app?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, sentiment-analysis, ibm-mobile-services, mobilefirst-qa

I need to add the MQA feedback tool to an existing hybrid app being develop with IBM MobileFirst.

Here is what I have done and what I need to do.

### Done:

- Downloaded the MQA sdk for MobileFirst JavaScript Hybrid SDK MFPComponent-JS-3.0.13
- Created a Bluemix account and a MQA app
- added IOS platform
- Added MQA as an application component using Eclipse (not sure if this is the correct way to do it)
- Creted a UI with a feedback form (rate experience, subject, comments, include my id in my feedback, submit button)

In this UI I created a toggle for enabling "Shake to see this screen".

### Need help to:

- check if the MQA library was added correctly. How can I test it?
- How can I make the submit button click event send the feedback data (UI form) to the MQA server? (any source code please?) I need to see the data in the MQA manager site.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to first follow the provided Getting Started tutorials, which will guide you through setting up the SDK and making sure that MQA is properly working in the application, including example code.

After that, once you get it working, you can come back with concrete questions on things that do not work.

See here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-2/quality-assurance/native-ios/